# Why can we extend linearly?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Often in linear algebra we define a map $f$ on some basis of a vector space $V$ and then say that we extend it linearly to a map $f : V \to V$.

That this should be possible seems obvious, but I've never actually seen a proof that this linear extension really exists. This strikes me as a bit odd since the proof of the uniqueness of this extension is often given in linear algebra courses.

Answer (score 4):

For easier notation suppose $V$ is finite dimensional and $B=\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ is a basis. Assume we have a map $f:B\to V$. Then we can define $F:V\to V$ by $F(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_if(b_i)$. This is a well defined function, because the representation $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ib_i$ of every element is unique. And it is easy to check that $F$ is linear. For example:

$F(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ib_i+\sum_{i=1}^n\beta_ib_i)=F(\sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha_i+\beta_i)b_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha_i+\beta_i)f(b_i)=$

$=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_if(b_i)+\sum_{i=1}^n\beta_if(b_i)$

Similarly show that $F$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: Oh yeah, duh. Thanks. I have seen this proof before. I just forgot how similar the well-definedness and existence proofs were. Both rely on unique basis representations.